# Hibernate says: table is not mapped -is it true?

Tags: java, hibernate

A database entity (a database contains table `topics`):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "topics")
public class Topic { ...
```

service method:

```
String queryString = "SELECT id FROM topics WHERE topic_name='" + topic_name + "'"; 
logger.debug(queryString); //SELECT id FROM topics WHERE topic_name='Chemistry'
Query query = session.createQuery(queryString); //an error is on this line
```

I get the error:

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: topics is not
>   mapped

What is wrong with entity mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be like this

```
String queryString = "SELECT id FROM Topic WHERE topic_name='" + topic_name + "'";
```

as your entity class is defined to be Topic.